# Load Content Dynamically With Ajax Into Each Pane Using Cool Menu

Tags: jquery, css

Please reference this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125237/load-content-dynamically-into-each-pane-using-cool-menu

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just try the tutorial that was posted in the post?
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/09/06/collapsing-site-navigation/